# Checking Internet connection and then changing image in JQuery/Javascript/Ajax in webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am looking for javascript/Jquery, I have setting icon image in my web page.

If there is no internet connection then my setting icon image must change automatically to other image. I know we can do with help of NavigatorOnLine.onLine, I can achieve this by any button click but I want it should load automatically, when page load.

Image must change depend open internet connection.Below code just for navigator onclick. Ihave searched but did not find any thing.

**javascript**

```
 function myFunction()
    {
    var x = "Is the browser online? " + navigator.onLine;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
    }
```

This all happen on page load without click event call:-

Here is updated code, In this I am trying to check internet connection is on or not. If connection is off then 'link' on the will be automatically disable(non clickable) and it bgcolor changes to red.

And if connection is off 'link' will be automatically get enable(clickable) and it bgcolor changes to green.
However I am missing some thing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.connected{ background-color:green;}
.diconnected{background-color:green;}
#link1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border: #0FF 1px solid;
}
</style>
<body>
<a href="#" id="link1"><img src="images/network.png"> My status</a>

</body>
<script>
window.onload=function() {
   var tId = setInterval(function() {
     document.getElementById("link1").disabled=!navigator.onLine;
   },500);
   if (navigator.onLine) {
       $("link1").bind('click', true).addClass('connected').removeclass('diconnected');

} else {
   $('.link1').unbind('click', false);
   $("link1").bind('click', true).addClass('diconnected').removeclass('diconnected');
}

}

</script>
</html>
```

Code
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you stuck??? You didn't need to click to get `navigator.onLine` to work

Comment: simple solution for checking online status: point to an image you know exists online and check for an error event. if the url is bad (or the image resource cannot be found) you get an error event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/error - here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/vD3Wm/ (warning, alerts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to get the image locally if there is not connection.

```
$(function() {
  if (!navigator.onLine) $("#myImage").prop("src","data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
});
```

assuming

```
<img src="greendot.gif" id="myImage" />
```

You can create a function and run it using setInterval if you want to see it change between states:

```
$("#myImage").prop("src",navigator.online?"greendot.gif":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
```

Using a link and timeout

```
window.onload=function() {
   var tId = setInterval(function() {
     document.getElementById("link1").disabled=!navigator.onLine;
   },500);
}

<a href="whatever.html" id="link1" onclick="return navigator.onLine">Click or not</a>
```

Or using some of the code from your update

```
$(function() {
  $("link1").on('click',function(e) {
    if (!navigator.onLine) e.preventDefault();
   });

  var tId = setInterval(function() {
    $("link1").toggleClass('connected',navigator.onLine);
  },500);
});
```

Comment: ok I will not use image, if I just want to make that image as non clickable if no connection is there, previously it was clickable when connection is there).

Comment: :Thanks Sir. I agree with you. But I want without any click on (button/link), my button/link get enable and disable depending on internet condition.

Comment: As I said, use setInterval

Comment: Replace my disabled code with your bind using on and off

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49688/discussion-between-mike-phils-and-mplungjan)